# MySQL "Incorrect string value" error in function / stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to assign the output of the following statement to a variable in a MySQL FUNCTION or STORED PROCEDURE:

```
SELECT CAST(0xAAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF AS CHAR(28));
```

All I get is this:

> Error Code: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x81\xEC\x92\x01I\x06...' for column 'some_output' at row 1

This is obvious, but somehow couldn't solve it.

I read about all other CHARSET/COLLATION solutions, but that didn't help me.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `function_name`(`some_input` VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8mb4
BEGIN
    DECLARE some_output CHAR(50) CHARSET utf8mb4;
    SET some_output = SELECT CAST(0xAAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF AS CHAR(28));
    RETURN some_output;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> **[Hexadecimal Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)**
>   ... In string contexts hexadecimal values act like binary strings ...

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name() RETURNS VARBINARY(28)
RETURN 0xAAAAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87785/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking like a computer.  Databases tend to conceptualize strings in a more human-relevant way than you may be accustomed to.  This used to drive me nuts.

It's logically sensible that if I have a 'string' then I should be able to store anything from 0x00 to 0xFF in each byte position, yeah?  Well, no, because the "CHAR" in `VARCHAR` is for "character" (not the same as "byte").

You might concur, based on the result of the following logical test, that databases seem to have a different idea of what makes up a "string" ...

```
mysql> SELECT 'A' = 'a';
+-----------+
| 'A' = 'a' |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

True? Wait, in what kind of crazy universe is that true?  It's true in a universe with collations, which determine sorting and matching among characters (as opposed to bytes)... and go hand in hand with character sets, which map the bits of a character to the visual representation of a character.  Within a character set, not every possible combination of bytes is a valid character.

A moment's reflection suggests that a world where 0x41 ("A") is considered equal to 0x61 ("a") is no place for binary data.

```
Incorrect string value: '\x81\xEC\x92\x01I\x06...'
```

UTF-8 is backwards compatible with good ol' ASCII only for values of 0x7F and below, with larger values in a given byte position indicating that the single "character" starting at that byte position is actually also composed of one or more subsequent bytes, and valid values for those bytes are determined by the design of UTF-8, where multibyte characters are constrained like this:

> The leading byte has two or more high-order 1s followed by a 0, while continuation bytes all have '10' in the high-order position.
>
> <sup>— http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description</sup>

Thus, the byte 0x81 (10000001) is not a valid character in a UTF-8 string unless it is preceded by a byte with a value >= 0xC0... so what you have there is an invalid UTF-8 string that you're trying to store in a structure that by definition requires valid UTF-8.

The structure you are looking for is the blissfully character set and collation unaware [VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html) for storing arbitrary strings of bytes that are relevant to algorithms, as opposed to [VARCHAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html), for storing strings of characters that are (presumably) relevant to human communication.